# How to find the pdf of two independent random variable pdf is known and its limits

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given two statistically independent random variable X and Y, where $ f_X(x) =\frac{2x^{-\frac{m+4}{m +2}}}{(m + 2)r_e^2}, x \in [x_{min}, x_{max}] $ and $Y$ follows a distribution of $f_Y(y)  = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - y^2}}, y \in [-1, 1]$ then what is the pdf of its product of two distribution $Z = XY$
Here  $x_{min} = \left( l^2 + r_e^2 \right)^{-\frac{m + 2}{2}}$
and $x_{max} = \left(l^2\right)^{-\frac{m + 2}{2}}$ Here $r_e, m, l$ are constants.
and what is the range ?
From [Product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) I got the pdf of $f_Z(z) = \frac{2z^{-\frac{m +4}{m + 2}}}{\pi (m + 2) r_e^2} \beta\left(\frac{m + 4}{2m +4},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ , where $\beta(.)$ represents beta function. However when I am integrating $f_Z(z)$ I am not able to get 1 . So please say what should be its range of $f_Z(z)$.

From [the product distribution}

Comment: try integrating from $-x_{max}$ to $x_{max}$

Comment: @Snoop yes already have tried however it is not coming.. can you please try.